# Connect to a AWS mysql instance on express server (typescript)

Tags: mysql, typescript, amazon-web-services, express

This is the first time I'm trying to connect to a AWS MySQL instance in an express app with TypeScript, and I'm getting errors like

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

even if I change the port to a number, I get an error for the entire object passed to this connection.

This is how I'm trying:

```
import * as express from "express"
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as mysql from 'mysql'

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
  user     : process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  password : process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  port     : process.env.RDS_PORT,
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Connected to database.');
});

connection.end();

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.send({test: "hello world"})
})

export default app
```

Apparently, this is JavaScript and not TypeScript so I need a way to convert it?

Comment: you want a solution in javascript or typeScript ? what you posted is a code snippet from AWS docs, Can you post your code also?

Comment: in typescript. This exactly what I have in my app. I've added the rest of the boilerplate now

Comment: If you are using typescript then have you tried typeorm?